# Log FTP connection failures

Tags: iis, ftp

I have a FTP server (IIS) in cloud. It deals with files (text) having size in GB sometimes. Customers are complaining about the connection failures or download/upload failures.
Is there any way I can log any failed (negative) action performed with my FTP server?

I have tried IFtpLogProvider in .Net but it does not give me valid FTP Status.
for example, if I start an upload & download from client & disconnect the network, still it records status as 226 which is successful transfer.
Either I am missing something with IFtpLogProvider or I have misunderstood the codes.

Is there any other way to record all the FTP transactions which will allow me to investigate the issue being faced by my customers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a silly mistake. I did not enable FTP Extensibility in Windows Features within IIS. Once enabled, it started working.